# dropzone icons show outside of dropzone

Tags: css, dropzone

When I upload multiple files using [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/), the icons display outside of the box.
I this picture, the dropzone form is yellow in the picture below, but when I choose many files, they overflow it and show outside of the form.
My dropzone's CSS is

```
#my-dropzone{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:var(--lightYellow);
    border:1pt solid #555;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

I'm guessing this is a CSS issue, but I can't figure it out. I've tried adding

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

to try and add a scroll but that doesn't do anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my CSS to

```
#my-dropzone{
    width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    height:auto;
    background:var(--lightYellow);
    border:1pt solid #555;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

The key was to use min-height. I had it set to a static 300px height which kept it from resizing itself.